Jenkins - How to properly checkout to github to build docker-compose
Docker-compose file is located in Github, looking for a proper way to checkout to Github project master branch and do docker-compose up
trying to access it from Jenkin by using the following code, but this just pulls the entire repo.
  stages {
        stage('Clone Git Repository') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: "GitSCM",
                        branches: [[name: "*/master"]],
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "git@github.com:repo/project.git"]]
                ]);
            }
        }

That works, but then Jenkins looks for the docker-compose file in jenkins workspace and not the repo
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deployment/repo v4/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

sh "git clone git@github.com:repo/project.git"?

@KamilCuk that works, but then when I specify the docker-compose file in my next step, Jenkins searches the file from workspace, not the github folder

sooo cd project? Did you try it from the terminal? It's the same. Every sh "" is a separate shell session.

Dockerfile and docker-compose should be at the root of git repository. Share us the file/folder structure of your git repository
